# "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor: No such file or directory" while working with TensorFlow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, eigen3

I'm trying to use tensorflow as a external library in my C++ application (mainly following [this tutorial](https://tebesu.github.io/posts/Training-a-TensorFlow-graph-in-C++-API)). What I done so far:

1. I have cloned the tensorflow reporitory (let's say, that the repo root dir is `$TENSORFLOW`)
2. Run `/.configure` (which all settings default, so no CUDA, no OpenCL etc.).
3. Build shared library with `bazel build -c /opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so` (build completed successfully)
4. Now I'm trying to `#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"`. But after including it (and adding `$TENSORFLOW` and `$TENSORFLOW/bazel-genfiles` to include path), I'm receiving error:

   ```
   $TENSORFLOW/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:42:
   fatal error: unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor: No such file or directory
   ```

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4680) created for similar problem, but it's marked as closed without any solution provided. Also I tried with `master` branch as well as `v.1.4.0` release.

Do you happen to know, what could cause this kind of problem and how to deal with it?

Comment: Well asked; also can be an issue with tensorflow 1.12 (and I suspect pretty much every version)

Answer (score 5):

I (and many others) agonized over the same problem.  It probably can be solved using bazel but I don't know that tool well enough and now I solve this using make.  The source of confusion is that a file named Tensor is included and it itself includes a file named Tensor, which has caused some people to wrongly conclude Tensor is including itself.

If you built and installed the python .whl file there will be a tensorflow directory in dist-packages and an include directory below that, e.g. on my system:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include
```

From the include directory

```
find . -type f -name 'Tensor' -print
./third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor
./external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor
```

The first one has

```
#include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
```

and the file that should satisfy this is the second one.

So to compile session.cc that includes session.h, the following will work

```
INC_TENS1=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/
INC_TENS2=${INC_TENS1}external/eigen_archive/
gcc -c -std=c++11 -I $INC_TENS1 -I $INC_TENS2 session.cc
```

I've seen claims that you must build apps from the tensorflow tree and you must use bazel.  However, I believe all the header files you need are in dist-packages/tensorflow/include and at least for starters you can construct makefile or cmake projects.

Comment: This works perfectly fine with g++ but the same path when added to cmake throws a  n error ```/usr/local/include/google/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:10: fatal error: 'unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor' file not found
#include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"```
Did you ever try this with cmake?

Comment: This worked for me for tensorflow 1.12; although my include directory is somewhere else (depends on how it is installed).  Agree with the answer, this seems to be assuming you're using bazel to build the project but I also don't have the expertise and keep running into issues with it making it difficult.  I'd assume the cmake find package for tensorflow would report out these include directories?

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off-topic, but I had the same error with a C++ project using opencv-4.5.5 and compiled with Visual Studio (no problem with opencv-4.3.0, and no problem with MinGW).

To make it work, I had to add to my root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-DOPENCV_DISABLE_EIGEN_TENSOR_SUPPORT)
```

If that can help someone...

Answer (score 1):

the problem was actually in the relative path of the header file taken in the Tensor file.

installed path for Tensor is /usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor

but mentioned in the Tensor file is "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"

So there should be an entry upto /usr/include/eigen3/ in the project path to run this correctly so that it can be used.

Comment: That would presumably cause it to try to include itself; confusingly there is actually another Tensor.h file elsewhere (poor naming choice).

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

copy it for convenient search

```
sudo cp -r /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen /usr/include &&
sudo cp -r /usr/include/eigen3/signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library /usr/include &&
sudo cp -r /usr/include/eigen3/unsupported /usr/include
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).