# Issues including Eigen for simple C++ TensorFlow Lite test program

Tags: c++, include-path, eigen3, tensorflow-lite

I compiled the library for the C++ API for TensorFlow Lite (r1.97) using the script `${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_rpi_lib.sh` following the steps suggested at this official [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/rpi) (Native Compiling, downloading the necessary libraries), where `${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}` is the root folder where I cloned the repository.

I am trying to compile this simple `test.cpp` program:

```cpp
#include <memory>

#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"

int main(void)
{
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter(new tflite::Interpreter);
}
```

using the command:

```
gcc-6 test.cpp -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT} -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/protobuf/src -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads -L${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv7l/lib -lstdc++ -ldl -ltensorflow-lite
```

The list of includes was suggested in the [Integrating TensorFlow libraries](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tfmobile/linking_libs) page (specifically from the section iOS). Compilation fails with the following error related to the inclusion of Eigen:

```
${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:42: fatal error: unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor: No such file or directory
 #include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
```

I found several links where an apparently similar problem is discussed (such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731174/unsupported-eigen-cxx11-tensor-no-such-file-or-directory-while-working-with-t?rq=1)), but the proposed solutions involve using references to the TensorFlow python package which is something that is not possible in my case (and it feels quite patchy - I am not considering using python for this project).

I also tried using a different include path to Eigen (e.g. `${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/third_party/eigen3`):

```
gcc-6 test.cpp -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT} -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/third_party/eigen3 -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/protobuf/src -I${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads -L${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv7l/lib -lstdc++ -ldl -ltensorflow-lite
```

and also this causes Eigen related compilation errors of this sort:

```
...
${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:1:42: error: #include nested too deeply
 #include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
...
${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/third_party/eigen3/Eigen/Core:1:22: error: #include nested too deeply
 #include "Eigen/Core"
...
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? What is the right set of include paths?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was including the wrong folder. Instead of `${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen` or `${TENSORFLOW_ROOT}/third_party/eigen3`, the right one is `${TFLITE_ROOT}/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/eigen`.

I am still puzzled by the number of `eigen` folders inside the repository:

```
find . -name "eigen*" -type d                                                                                                                                             
./third_party/eigen3
./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/eigen
```